# Prevent deadlocks in multi threaded environment when using Oracle Update clause

Tags: multithreading, jdbc, oracle19c, database-deadlocks

I have a multi threaded application connecting to Oracle 19c DB. There is a process table where another application is constantly writing new records. Purpose of the threads in app is to pickup records to be processed in parallel, do some processing and update status in table as COMPLETED.

To ensure that each thread works on unique records from process table, we use below approach -

1. Each thread first selects available records for processing from process table and sets a particular column named "THREAD-ID" value to its unique thread id.
2. Next it queries records having only its thread id from process table and processes them.

This is causing deadlocks occasionally b/w threads. One approach suggested is to refactor SQL as below -

```
UPDATE PROCESS_TABLE SET THREAD-ID = <thread id> 
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM PROCESS_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'PENDING' AND THREAD-ID = 'UNASSIGNED'
)
```

I do not have any other high concurrency environment apart from PROD where this deadlock issue is happening. So I cannot test conclusively if above fix will solve the issue. Can anyone advise if above approach will solve deadlock. If yes, what is the justification that can be given for above fix?

Comment: Whenever you have an Oracle deadlock (which raises the error ORA-00060), you should get the relevant trace file from the database. That trace file will tell you exactly what objects and statements are involved with the deadlock. Without that information, you can only guess at the problem and the solution. Perhaps your deadlock could be fixed by indexing a foreign key, or removing a bitmap index, or changing a table property. Before you change your application logic, check that trace file.

Comment: Thanks for the details @JonHeller. In general what is the difference (if any) between below two flavors of SQL especially w.r.t concurrency - 1) UPDATE PROCESS_TABLE SET THREAD-ID = <thread id> WHERE STATUS = 'PENDING' AND THREAD-ID = 'UNASSIGNED'  and 2) UPDATE PROCESS_TABLE SET THREAD-ID = <thread id> 
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM PROCESS_TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'PENDING' AND THREAD-ID = 'UNASSIGNED'
)                                    Assuming there is no index on STATUS and/or THREAD-ID

Comment: It's hard to say which query is better for preventing deadlocks. I would bet on the first query, since it is likely faster, which means it will hold locks for less time and is therefore less likely to create a situation where two sessions try to lock the same row. Possibly you might get lucky, and one of the queries would have a different execution plan that would lock rows in a different order. But don't program based on luck - you should understand exactly what your deadlock is caused by before you try to fix it.